# Android: live data set from fragment is not triggered in activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

Here is my vm in kotlin:

```
class DataViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _pcs : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
    var pcs : LiveData<ArrayList<String>> = _pcs
    private var manualPcs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    private var _weight : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
    var weight : LiveData<ArrayList<String>> = _pcs
    private var manualWeight: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    private var _rfs : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
    var rfs : LiveData<ArrayList<String>> = _pcs
    private var rfIDs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()


    fun setDashBoardData(data: ArrayList<TidDetailsHolder>) {
        manualPcs.clear()
        manualWeight.clear()
        rfIDs.clear()
        for (item in data) {
            when (item.type) {
                "Manual By Pcs" -> {

                    manualPcs.add(item.gettID())
                }
                "Manual By Weight" -> {

                    manualWeight.add(item.gettID())
                }
                else -> {

                    rfIDs.add(item.gettID())
                }
            }
        }
        _pcs.postValue(manualPcs)
        _weight.postValue(manualWeight)
        _rfs.postValue(rfIDs)
        Debug.i("alert 1: manual pcs ${manualPcs.size} weight ${manualWeight.size} rfid ${rfIDs.size}");
    }

}
```

Fragment in java:

```
private DataViewModel dataViewModel;
```

initialized in oncreate :

```
dataViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DataViewModel.class);
```

My activity:

similarly initialized in oncreate and the observers are set

```
dataViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DataViewModel.class);
        Debug.i("alert 1: vm hash ac" + dataViewModel.hashCode());
        dataViewModel.getPcs().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<String> strings) {
                Debug.i("alert 1: by pcs " + strings.size());
            }
        });

        dataViewModel.getWeight().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<String> strings) {
                Debug.i("alert 1: by weight " + strings.size());
            }
        });
```

the observables are not triggered, also if it matters the hashcode of the vm in the fragment and activity is different. What am I missing here ??

Comment: Is your fragment hosted in that activity? i.e. are you passing the same object to both ``ViewModelProvider``s? Also all your public ``LiveData``s are referencing ``_pcs``

Comment: I changed the reference to _pcs, even then the observeable is not working. No the fragment is in one activity and I am observing it from another activity

Comment: Is this happening due to the different activities ?

Comment: When you create a ``ViewModelProvider`` you're passing an ``Activity`` - this lets the system create a ``ViewModel`` for that activity class, shared by all instances of that activity. If an activity is destroyed, the next instance will get the same VM with the data still in it. And if a ``Fragment`` passes its parent activity to that constructor, it will get the ``Activity``'s VM, which allows all the fragments in an activity to share the same VM. But when you pass in the results of ``requireActivity()`` here, because this is a different activity, you get a different VM. If that makes sense?

Comment: so using a base activity should work right ?

Comment: If both ``ViewModelProvider()`` calls are passing *the same class* of ``Activity`` then they'll both get the same VM back, i.e. it'll be shared. But if one's passing an ``ActivityA`` and the other's passing ``ActivityB``, they'll get different VMs, even if both those classes have ``BaseActivity`` as a superclass. The way it's designed, I don't think you're *supposed to* be sharing VMs between activities - they're more of a way to keep data in memory when an activity is destroyed and recreated (e.g. rotation) and to let multiple fragments in a single activity share data and react to events

Comment: You should probably be persisting your data in your first activity (like to a database, SharedPreferences, the new DataStore stuff) and then having a separate VM for the other activity, which loads that same data and allows the Fragment to observe it. Don't think of it like a single source of data, so there's just one ViewModel - you tend to have a separate ViewModel for every UI screen, and that allows the UI to observe certain things and display them, and to pass events and user choices to the rest of the app. That's how it's designed in Android (and they recommend single-activity too)